# Bound effect life-cycle to angular component

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Our application has some global actions that need to be handled within several effects. This effects load some data from back-end and then through reducer it puts it in a store. But, when component doesn't exist we don't need to update the store, and perform redundant BE calls.

How it can be handled?

Due to some requirements we can't rely on route or on business logic.
Are there any general solution? Or this approach is 100% anti-pattern?

Comment: Could you use a property in your store to determine if your component is active and use a selector to that property in your effect so it only fetches the data from your back-end when that property is true?

Comment: I thought about that. But what if it will be multiply instances or components? And I am not sure if it is a right way to do that.

Comment: If you multiply the instances, then the property could be the number of active components, you could use 2 actions (activate and deactivate) to increase/decrease this count, and the selector used by the effect would be a boolean selector, checking if the count is greater than 0. Upon creation, each component would dispatch the activate action to increase the count, and they would dispatch the deactivate action to decrease it. Only when the count reaches 0 the selector will return false your effect stop fetching data from the back-end.

Comment: Yeah, this might be the option. If we found nothing better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without more information I think there are two other options besides keeping a property in state:

- Create a separate lazy loaded module for the components + effects. The effect (and components) will only by registered when the module is loaded
- Use the `OnRunEffects` lifecycle as documented in the [NgRx docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/lifecycle). You can "power on/off" the effects via this way.